# Static IP Address in Android x86 persistent after reboot?

Tags: networking, android-x86

I would like to have a static ipaddress on my Android_x86.

I know there is a lot of questions about this and i tried some proposed answer, like :

```
su
ifconfif eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 [IP] netmask [masque] up
```

It works, but these changes are removed after a reboot. It's a big problem in my case. I tried some solutions like edit the init.sh, or third party app on the store, but neither works.

What should I do ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score -1):

I did it, editing the file /etc/init.sh did the trick for me.
just adding at the end :

```
ifconfig eth0 [IP] netmask [masque] up
```

It should be ran at boot.

Comment: but what if it says "unknows id" to ifconfig?

Comment: I would love to help you but I can't remember anything about this, it was some little internship project. Sorry !

Comment: ifconfig eth0 [IP] doesn't seem to work in Android x86 7.1

Comment: `/etc/init.sh` isn't a universal solution, very ROM-specific.